# Xcode: Cocos2d: Can't create world with Box2D

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

My project originated as the cocos2d Box2D template and I'm having issues as soon as I tried to create a world:

```
world = new b2World(gravity,doSleep);
```

Gives the error: No matching constructor for initialization of 'b2World'.

The file is .mm, I assume it's some issue about library linking maybe? If so I'm using xCode 4, how can I check the lib is properly linked?

Thanks.

Comment: Which cocos2d version are you using? If it's cocos2d 2.0 alpha then that should come with an updated "cocos2d with box2d" project template.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are using Box2D v2.2 or newer. The [b2World constructor](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Box2D/html/classb2_world.html) no longer takes two arguments, just one (gravity). You have to set doSleep separately:

```
world = new b2World(gravity);
world->SetAllowSleeping(doSleep);
```

This won't be the only change you'll need to make to transition from Box2D v2.1.x to v2.2.x. [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) has a working Box2D 2.2.1 sample project, even if you don't use Kobold2D you can get updated source code for Box2D basics. In particular the GLESDebugDraw class and how to setup a screen bounding box with a body using multiple shapes.

Comment: Thank you Steffen. It seems Box2D official reference misses the update. http://box2d.org/manual.pdf  page 8 still has the old way of creating the world. BTW, you have set a very nice "listener port" for Cocos2D questions :).